# Binding DisplayDate and DisplayDateStart from another DatePicker Value

Tags: wpf

I have two date pickers. The first datepicker sets the second's DisplayDate and DisplayDateStart. The below code sets the DisplayDate and DisplayDateStart correct, the issue I have is that when I select a date with the second datepicker, it also updates the first datepicker selected date. May I ask how abouts do I fix this?

For example

```
DP1.SelectedDate = january 1 2017
```

if I change DP2.SelectedDate to be February 3 2017, DP1.SelectedDate gets changed to that as well.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<telerik:RadDatePicker  DisplayDateStart="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker, Mode=TwoWay}"
             DisplayDate="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I've also tried setting DisplayDateStart and DisplayDate to be OneWay but then DisplayDate doesn't work correctly, it shows DateTime.Now instead of showing DisbursalDatePicker.

I tried to make the post as simplistic as possible so anyone can test it but I believe this may be an issue with Telerik controls. The issue only occurs with telerik:RadDatePicker and not the wpf DatePicker

Comment: Try `DisplayDate="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker, Mode=OneWay}"` on the second date picker. What do you mean by "then DisplayDateStart doesn't work correctly"? What is the correct behavior, and what do you see instead?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Updated the post. Sorry, DisplayDateStart works correct with one way. DisplayDate is unchanged, displays DateTime.Now no matter what DisbursalDatePicker is changed to when Mode=OneWay

Comment: I can't figure out what the `DisplayDate` property is supposed to be for; [MSDN is as cryptic as it usually is with WPF properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydate(v=vs.110).aspx). But if I use `SelectedDate` on the second DatePicker as well as on the first, then the second DatePicker accurately reflects the value of `DisbursalDatePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

`Mode=TwoWay` is redundant on `DatePicker.SelectedDate`; when the dependency property is created, the framework makes that the default for bindings on the property.

`DatePicker.DisplayDate` doesn't seem to be good for much: All I can find by experimenting is that if `SelectedDate` is null, `DisplayDate` will be the initial highlighted date on the calendar popup. I can see how that's useful, but it's not what you want. [MSDN doesn't even admit to having a guess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydate(v=vs.110).aspx). MSDN's WPF documentation is a disappointment.

This works, if I understand your requirements:

```
<DatePicker 
    SelectedDate="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker}"/>

<DatePicker 
    DisplayDateStart="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker}" 
    SelectedDate="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker, Mode=OneWay}" 
    />
```

When I change the first date picker, it updates `DisplayDateStart` on the second. The second updates to display `DisbursalDatePicker` when `DisbursalDatePicker` changes, but does not update `DisbursalDatePicker` itself when I interact with it.

I'm not sure what it's good for, though, because the viewmodel can't get a value out of the second DatePicker. If it were me, I'd have two viewmodel properties: `DisbursalDatePicker` and `OtherDateValue`. `DisbursalDatePicker`'s setter would update `OtherDateValue` when `DisbursalDatePicker` changes, but not vice versa.

```
<DatePicker 
    SelectedDate="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker}"/>

<DatePicker 
    DisplayDateStart="{Binding DisbursalDatePicker}" 
    SelectedDate="{Binding OtherDateValue}" 
    />
```

I'd likely make the `DisbursalDatePicker` setter a little smarter: Update `OtherDateValue` only if `OtherDateValue`'s value has become invalid:

```
private DateTime _disbursalDatePicker = default(DateTime);
public DateTime DisbursalDatePicker
{
    get { return _disbursalDatePicker; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _disbursalDatePicker)
        {
            _disbursalDatePicker = value;
            if (OtherDateValue.CompareTo(DisbursalDatePicker) < 0)
            {
                OtherDateValue = DisbursalDatePicker;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```